# Neutral plug issue

Tags: neutral

I have three outlets (that I can find) that are showing open neutral. I have 80v across hot and neutral, 120v at hot to ground and 28v neutral to ground.
I also have one switch to a light that I think is on this circuit that is not working. If I pull the switch and wire it directly (white to white and black to black) my tester shows open neutral/ground on the same three plugs. When I ran an extension cord to the wires that goes to the light it will come on.
This is an older single wide trailer that I am trying to help a friend out.   Anyone have any thoughts or suggestions on what direction to go?

Comment: Probably a loose or corroded connection.  Would turn off the breaker and double check for power at each outlet/switch/breaker.  Pull them out of the wall and check connections for tightness/nasty looking stuff.  Check also for ground to neutral jumpers.

Comment: These are presumably on the same circuit? There's likely one bad connection, and it's either at the device that's bad and closest to the power panel (as the cable runs) or it's (coming out of) the last device on the same circuit (before that point) that's good.